# Why is the multibinding always passing DependencyProperty.UnsetValue for the first value?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

In a form in my WPF application, I am building a psuedo bar graph.  The bar graph consists of a Grid with 12 columns.  Each column contains a Rectangle.  I am using databinding to bind the height of the rectangle to the data that I want to graph.  The xaml looks like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlBorder}"
        BorderThickness="2"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="0,5"
        Name="SNRGraphBorder">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource TextForeground}"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="1,5,2,0"
                   Name="Data01"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Rectangle.Height>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ScaleData}">
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource XmlProvider}"
                             XPath="a:PathToData}" />
                    <Binding Path="RectangleHeight"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:MyControl}}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Rectangle.Height>
        </Rectangle>
        . . .
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I've only included one rectangle for brevity.

Here's the code for the IMultiValueConverter used in the MultiBinding:

```
public class ScaleDataConverter : IMultiValueConverter {

    public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) {
        double snr = 0.0;

        if ( values[ 0 ] is string ) {
            snr = double.Parse( values[ 0 ] as string );

        } else if ( values[ 0 ] is int || values[ 0 ] is double || values[ 0 ] is long || values[ 0 ] is float ) {
            snr = (double) values[ 0 ];
        } else {
            return values[ 0 ];
        }

        double ActualHeight = (double) values[ 1 ];
        return snr * ActualHeight / 99.0;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack( object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Finally, here's the code behind for this control:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl {

    public XmlDataProvider DataProvider { get; set; }

    public DeviceMonitor DeviceMonitor { get; set; }

    public double RectangleHeight {
        get { return SNRGraphBorder.ActualHeight; }
    }

    public MyControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataProvider = Resources[ "XmlProvider" ] as XmlDataProvider; 
    }

    private void GetDiagnosticsInfo() {
        if ( DeviceMonitor != null ) {
            XmlDocument diagnosticsDoc = new XmlDocument();
            string info = DeviceMonitor.GetDiagnosticInfo();
            diagnosticsDoc.LoadXml( info );
            DataProvider.Document = diagnosticsDoc;
        }
    }

    private void RefreshButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
        GetDiagnosticsInfo();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I've put breakpoints into the converter on the `if ( values[ 0 ] is string )` line.  I see that the first entry in the values array is always DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.  Yet I know that the XML has other data for this property.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: Did you add XmlDataProvider with key "XmlProvider" to Resources? And are you sure that "a:PathToData}" is correct? is one bracket?

Comment: Yes, I did add XmlDataProvider with key "XmlProvider" to Resources.  I just didn't show it in the example.  My XPaths are correct:  I had an earlier version of the code without the IMultiBinding and IMultConverter and I was able to see the data i nthat version.  The problem is that in every call to the IMultiConverter, the first parameter is always DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

Comment: hm.. interesting.. and 'RectangleHeight' has correct value in 'IMultiValueConverter'?

Comment: Yes.  It happens to be 0 because I haven't set it yet, but I'm still seeing DependencyProperty.UnsetValue always for the first binding.  This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to resolve the issue.  If you look closely at the XPath in the first multi binding, you'll see that it ends in a "}".  That character is not actually a part of the XPath, it is a left-over from the original text for the binding when it was a single binding using the {Binding Source={...} XPath=....} syntax.  Once I removed it, I stopped getting `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` for the first value in the values array.

I was also able to resolve the other issue with the second value being zero.  I made the RectangleHeight property a `DependencyProperty` and added code in the Loaded event handler to set it equal to the actual height of the `Grid` control that contains all of the `Rectangles`.  Now my code works and I get a lovely bar graph.

Thanks all who looked.

Comment: Moreover add code that set RectangleHeight in SizeChanged event too

Comment: Same thing happened to me after all those years, only with a RelativeSource binding. I checked if the syntax of my RelativeSource binding was wrong, but didn't think of checking the syntax for its Path. Getting rid of the extra } at the end finally resolved the issue.